How to send an array from c# to matlab script?
I want to pass a number of arrays as input to matlab function and receive the result in .net6 web application? How to do so?
Here is an example of matlab code
function  [a, b, c] = myfunc(x)    % where x is an array
    a = x(1)+x(2);        % access array elements
    b = a;
    c = prod(x);          % x1*x2*x3...xn;
end 

and this in c# code:
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\myfunc.m");

object result = null;

int[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100, 500, 800, 14, 78, 99, 45, 201, 336, 5578 };
matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result, input);

// Display result 
object[] res = result as object[];

Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
Console.WriteLine(res[1]);
Console.WriteLine(res[3]);
Console.ReadLine();

it gives me an exception at this line:
matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result, input);
Exception is: Undefined function 'myfunc' for input arguments of type 'int32'

MLApp is a python library for doing math functions.  It is not Matlab.  You need to build a Matlab dll and the use DllImport to pass parameters to Matlab like a C Language Program.

Do you have a link explain this in details?

@jdweng This is literally the example from the MATLAB docs. Either there are two packages with the same name, or you’re wrong.

The code needs to be matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\user\Desktop”), this changes the current directory to where your script or function is, so that MATLAB is able to find it.

@CrisLuengo : Your link is not for MLApp.MLApp.

See https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/587036-c-code-sample-to-use-shared-library-dll-generated-from-embedded-coder

@CrisLuengo The example you've mentioned is working fine with full path script but only in case the inputs of the matlab function are integer. When I tried to pass an array as input to matlab function, it gives me an exception.

@jdweng MLApp.MLApp is for the matlab COM server I added as a COM reference in my project.

How to pass arrays is shown on this page. If that doesn’t work, please [edit] this post to show your new code and error messages (as long as you don’t have an answer, it’s OK to change the question).

@jdweng click to expand the C# code.

@CrisLuengo : MLApp is a python script and not Matlab.  You are referencing Matlab.  The OP has this posting label wrong.

@jdweng Yes, there is a Python package called mlapp: https://pypi.org/project/mlapp/ — that doesn’t mean it is not also MATLAB. Multiple things can have the same name.

@CrisLuengo : MLApp may be equivalent to Matlab, but it is not Matlab.  Matlab is a company that make a Math Library. MLApp is IBM.

It worked when I've changed this line
matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\myfunc.m");

to
matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\user\Desktop");

and change also the number of outputs returned from matlab function in this line
matlab.Feval("myfunc", 3, out result, input);
